# What's the reason for IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed?

Tags: django, database

I'm doing the polls apps in Django Documentation: [Writing your first Django app, part 2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial02/). While working with Database API, I've found an IntegrityError.

polls/models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

I've tried to create an object of Question model.

```
Question.objects.create(question_text="What's up?")
```

This gives an error

> IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: polls_question.pub_date

But when i try this

```
Question.objects.create(pub_date=timezone.now())
```

It creates an object successfully.

What's the reason for IntegrityError in the first case and why it doesn't generate any error in the second case?

Comment: You have failed to mention which backend you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From django [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null)

> Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and TextField. If a string-based field has null=True, that means it has two possible values for “no data”: NULL, and the empty string. In most cases, it’s redundant to have two possible values for “no data;” the Django convention is to use the empty string, not NULL.

- So if `null=False`(default), django will use empty string (means not
  NULL)
- If `null=True`, Field can write `NULL` (means `None` comes to python)

**So in brief**:
    Django will not raise `IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint` for `CharField` and `TextField`.

Comment: plz explain the case I asked, aaccording to your answer.

Comment: That is what i answered.More info-> `Question.objects.create(pub_date=timezone.now())` will set `question_text` as empty string(means not NULL).Thats why it is not raising error.